# ListView does not resize when hiding element(s) dynamically

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a menu ListView that has a dynamic SignOut row that should only show when the user is logged in.  The ListView has a drop shadow after it (not set as a Footer, but rather as a View following the ListView).  When I remove the SignOut row it disappears, but the size of the ListView does not change, so there is a transparent gap and then the dropshadow.  I am hiding the SignOut row using `signOutBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);` (I have a reference to the signOutBtn View, which is a RelativeLayout).  Also, I have verified I am not using View.INVISIBLE anywhere since I would expect this behavior using that.

The ListView is using `wrap_content` for the height, and I believe this is where the problem lies - the height is being calculated including the SignOut button.

So, the question is, how can I make the ListView dynamically resize when a row is shown or hidden?  I would prefer not to destroy and recreate the View, although that is what I will probably try next, since it is a relatively simple view.

PS. I can add code samples if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide an item in a listview in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041499/how-to-hide-an-item-in-a-listview-in-android)

Comment: do you use an actual ListView? If you do, where do you set the button's visibility? Instead of setting the visibility you should remove the according list item from the list. I just assume that the listview would render the same size for each element, even if the element's view is gone...

Comment: @jpm, yes, it's an actual ListView, and if I need to actually remove and then add the View I'll go that route.  Wanted to make sure there wasn't something else I was overlooking first, being relatively new to Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I decided to just update the adapter data and remove or add the signOut row based on the user's login state.  It was pretty simple, and I was able to remove quite a few conditionals based around showing / hiding the button, plus code that was there to assign a unique id to the signOut button in the ListView adapter so I could look it up to hide it.