# How to make a navigation drawer list item GONE, not INVISIBLE

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, visibility

An app has a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). I tried to return a View with its visibility set to GONE in getView() of the the drawer's custom ArrayList adapter, the drawer still has blank space for the item. It is invisible, not gone. Is there a way to make it gone without changing the list?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(iDrawerItemLayoutId, null);
        }
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return v;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041499/how-to-hide-an-item-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: @Natix Thank you for the pointer. Yes, that is the same question.  My search missed it.  Maybe I should delete my question.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to update the adapter and then refresh the ListView by calling its `notifydatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Do you mean that I have to remove the item from the list to make it gone?

Comment: Yes, you will have to delete the item, but from the adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  As stated in my question, I was looking for a method without having to change the list.  It looks like that is impossible.