# Modify Firebase List Adapter based on seek bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to modify the output of a Firebase list adapter based on how far the location (e.g. restaurant) is away from user.....however this distance can not be calculated backend and included in the database query.....so instead I need to calculate distance as part of the populateView method.

I have a seek bar where use can change distance and thus filter the list returned (based on new distance)....however I have 2 problems.

1. How do I ensure populateView re-fires every time user touches seek bar (onProgressChanged)
2. How do I hide/show rows (views) during populateView.

Thanks alot

Comment: Sorry - #2 should read "How do I hide/show rows (views) during populateView"

Comment: figures out #1.....added  fireAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); into setOnSeekBarChangeListener........however answer to # 2 would be super useful if its possible!!!

Comment: might help you in #2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041499/how-to-hide-an-item-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: It does help; thanks