# Hiding items in listview properly

Tags: android, android-listview, hide

I would like to show/hide items in my listview. Currently I am doing this by iterating through adapter's data. If item at certain index matches some condition, this line is called:

```
listView.getChildAt(index).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Item is not visible, but blank space remains (surprisingly View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE acts the same in this case). 
I would like to achieve the same effect as if item was deleted from adapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()` was called, but I don't want to modify underlying data, just hide the item.

Comment: Filter the data first in adapter and never add it to the listview. It's so simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to hide a ListView Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638160/android-how-to-hide-a-listview-item)

Answer (score 5):

I have achieved this as Tonithy suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638160/android-how-to-hide-a-listview-item). Added an if clause at the begining of getView method in adapter, which checks if item matches condition to hide. If it does getView returns "null layout".

When I want to hide an item, I set a condition and call .invalidateViews() on my listview.

Comment: The worst practice I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not return different views based on internal property without letting listview know about it, you should reuse views!** Otherwise you make very slow apps. For example, take look at [this tutorial with benchmark](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;?v=T000000065).

- [`getView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) - reuse `convertView`!, hide it conditionaly!
- use [`Holder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) classes, make them "listen" to your adapter signals/evens and change their visual conditionally

Alternative: You can use **multiple types of list items within single list**:

- define list item types `(shown, hidden)`, override [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()): `return 2`
- override [`getItemViewType(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)),

  - `is shown -> 0`
  - `is not shown -> 1`
- more complex [`getView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup))

  - get item view type or check if it's shown
  - dispatch view creation based on type, don't forget, that `convertView` argument is view for current item type, you **should reuse it**, if not null!
- on change call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

I have tested approached like this for different stable types, but it should work even when type for item changes and you let observer know about it. This approach will be a lot of faster than one you have posted, because, you reuse views, don't need to always inflate new one!

Answer (score -1):

Call .setVisibility(View.GONE) in override getView method of your CustomeListAdapter for all UI elements of your custom_list_item.

For Example:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

    holder.tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if (items[position].NeedForCollapsed){
        System.out.println("set Visibility.Gone");
        holder.tvName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return rowView;
    }

    //new values
    holder.tvName.setText(items[position].name);
    holder.img.setImageResource(GetImageID(items[position]));

    return rowView;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tvName;
    ImageView img;
}
```

Or call .setVisibility(View.GONE) for your root container like a LinearLayout.
good luck!