# Android : setting visible to gone at runtime leaves an empty space

Tags: android

[image]

As shown in the image, there is layout A in my listview. Consider a button at top right of each square. If we click it, it will hide the RelativeLayout i.e set its visibility to gone.

```
holder.imgBtn= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
    holder.rLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rLayout);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

holder.imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        holder.rLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

But why there is still a space?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ibutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >


 //some code



</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: post the code snippet ?

Comment: Are you putting 1 part of a listview item GONE, or the entire item?  I don't think listview is made so that you can set an item as invisible (although if 1 item has multiple subviews, those subviews can be set to gone).

Comment: check other view in activity xml `layout_height`

Comment: notify your adapter for the change..it will remove that blank

Comment: @MeenalSharma it'll not change anything. see Gabe Sechan's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution from here: [Android: How to hide a ListView Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638160/android-how-to-hide-a-listview-item)

> What I ended up doing was creating a "null item" layout in xml and returned that based upon my criteria instead of the convert view in getView()...
>
> instead of returning the convertView, I returned my null_item...

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.null_item, null);
null_item.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>
```

That said, you might just be better off removing the item from your list and updating your data set.  That might be easier.