# How to remove an item from a listview inside the getItemView() method of the adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I want to check for a condition, and if so, I want to hide the item inside that method. I don't think I can use the position of the item because I'm in the method. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

code:

```
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent){

        if(v == null){
            v = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.adapter_item, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);
        ParseUser current = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        Order order = (Order) object;

        TextView t1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        if(current.getUsername().equals(order.getString("userA"))){
            if(order.getBoolean("newA") == true){
                t1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                t2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }

            if(order.getBoolean("hideA") == true){
                //hide item
            }
        }

        }

        return v;



    }
```

Comment: How are you trying to hide the item? If you are talking about hiding that row then you can set the visibility to `gone`

Comment: Wouldn't that take up space, though? And how would I go about hiding the entire row?

Comment: No. `v.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: Or, you might check these conditions *before* setting your adapter then removing/not adding them from/to the list

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638160/android-how-to-hide-a-listview-item

Answer (score 1):

```
    t1.setText("");
    t2.setText("");
```

Not the best solution but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Might also this work:

```
yourListItem.remove(itemA);
yourListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChange();
```